# Forced a Reference Type to be passed by value (or .Clone()d on Pass)

Tags: c#, reference

I have a math class (Vector3) that represents the 3 axis (x-y-z) with 3 floats. I would like it to be forced passed as value, not reference, since it's really just... A value, not an object. Any way of doing that *automatically*? I know I can do .Clone() in each of my methods, but you understand this isn't optimal.

Comment: Can't you use a struct for Vector3 instead of a class? In C#/.NET structs are value type

Comment: Why isn't it a `struct`? Values should be immutable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't do that automatically, because `class`es are reference types by definition. You have to use a `struct` if that's what you want.